# Which of them is worth buying

Tags: graphics-cards

I'm planning to buy a graphics card for my ryzen 3 2200g such as Rx570 and i m getting this from three OEM like Asus, Gigabyte And Msi These are the models :-

1. Gigabyte Radeon RX570 4GB GDDR5 PCI-E Graphics Card [Here](https://www.amazon.in/Gigabyte-Radeon-RX570-GDDR5-Graphics/dp/B06Y3RT952/ref=pd_aw_sbs_147_3/258-1491696-2717612?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B06Y3RT952&pd_rd_r=0efcf766-8fdb-11e9-aa5b-718c334ba082&pd_rd_w=GlGMm&pd_rd_wg=3CHiL&pf_rd_p=564155af-9230-4bd9-8c20-2acdbab6d7e3&pf_rd_r=MAP4G0R9TV1C5GENHW5W&psc=1&refRID=MAP4G0R9TV1C5GENHW5W) price 13k for 4gb
2. MSI RX 570 ARMOR 8G OC Gaming 256-Bit 8gb Gdrr5 Directx Graphics Card
   [Here](https://www.amazon.in/gp/aw/d/B076Y93L8F/ref=psdcmw_1375354031_t1_B06Y5WGXX3) Price 16k for 8gb
3. ASUS ROG Strix Radeon RX 570 O4G Gaming OC Edition GDDR5 DP HDMI DVI VR Ready AMD Graphics Card (ROG-STRIX-RX570-O4G-GAMING) [Here](https://www.amazon.in/Strix-Radeon-Gaming-Graphics-ROG-STRIX-RX570-O4G-GAMING/dp/B06Y5WGXX3/ref=pd_aw_sbs_147_4/258-1491696-2717612?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B06Y5WGXX3&pd_rd_r=0efcf766-8fdb-11e9-aa5b-718c334ba082&pd_rd_w=GlGMm&pd_rd_wg=3CHiL&pf_rd_p=564155af-9230-4bd9-8c20-2acdbab6d7e3&pf_rd_r=MAP4G0R9TV1C5GENHW5W&psc=1&refRID=MAP4G0R9TV1C5GENHW5W) price 16k for 4gb

Which of three will be worth buying and which has the top performance will 8gb by msi is better than asus rog 4gb line up any suggestions and explanation all i need i will like to do gaming on 1080p such as Pubg and GTA V etc and little bit Vmware, Android studio etc which of them will fit with ryzen 3 2200g to get the best performance.

Comment: If you can buy the 8GB version, buy that one.

Comment: Will it perform better than asus rog 4gb i mean that line up is so powerful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The only notable difference between the two variants is the amount of VRAM

It's always nice to have the exta buffer, so I'd say go for the 8gb card, but if money is tight, there is nothing wrong with choosing the 4gb card. The only time it will really come into play is if you want to play a game, or run a simulation that is extremely demanding, i.e. that uses more than 4gb of VRAM.

I myself have a 4gb and a 8gb card, and the amount of games that are affected by the difference is very little. All three of these cards will however be bottlenecked, but not a lot. So I'd say for future proofing, go for the 8gb variant!

Edit - Another thing to look at are the display ports you'd be using. If you don't need a DVI port, rather go for the cards with DisplayPorts and HDMI ports

Comment: what if i go for rx580 4gb over rx570 8gb will be worth it or it's waste for me, i have budget of 270$ which is 16000 rs here because in future I'm going for 3rd generation ryzen processors so if you have any better suggestion would be great to me and as your answer will ryzen 3 2200g will bottleneck at 1080p gaming i just need 60fps for gaming since i have tight budget.

Comment: Honestly, I'd take the 8gb of VRAM over the 4gb Rx 580. But, I am more into running simulations that requires vram. If you are asking game to game opinion, take the RX 580.

Comment: Thanks for helping I'm going for msi rx 570 armor 8g since its 8gb vram plus overclockable at 270$ so didn't have to upgrade it for few years since 8gb vram is really a investment over 4gb at same price.